# PayPal Button API onApprove called twice

Tags: javascript, angular, api, button, paypal

Hi I'm using Angular 2+ to integrate the sandbox PayPal checkout button with my form and throughout most of the process it works fine. The issue I'm having is that the onApprove() method seems to get called twice after the process ends which I can see because the HTTP request I have in that method gets called twice.

I've tried looking online for anyone who has experienced a similar problem but I can't find any resources on how to fix it. I have a few warnings in Chrome's console but these seem to be unrelated to the problem.

The console.log statements in createSubscription and onCancel only print once so I think that eliminates the possibility of there being some kind of duplicate window.

My code seems to be fairly similar to everyone else's implementation which I've seen on the web which  is why I can't wrap my head around why it doesn't work.

component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

paypal.Buttons({

  onInit: (data, actions) => {

  },

  onClick: (actions) => {

  },

  createSubscription: (data, actions) => {

    return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': this.planID,
    });

  },

  onApprove: (data, actions) => {
    console.log(data + ' transaction approved');
    this.submitLoginDetails();
    //this.getSubcriptionDetails(data.subscriptionID);
    // use auth login method and redirect to /home
  },

  onCancel: (data) => {

    console.log('Transaction cancelled');

  },

  onError: (err) => {

    console.log(err);

  }

}).render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
```

}

component.html

```
<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
    <div id='payment' [hidden]="stepCounter!==2">

      <form #loginForm='ngForm'>
        <div id="user-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" required>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" ngModel minlength=1 #name='ngModel'>
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf='(!name.valid || name.value.length === 0) && name.touched'>Please enter a valid name</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" required email>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" ngModel email #email='ngModel'>
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf='(!email.valid || email.value.length === 0) && email.touched'>Please enter a valid email</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ngModel required minlength=6 #password='ngModel'>
          <span class="help-block" *ngIf='(!password.valid || password.value.length === 0) && password.touched'>Please enter at least six characters</span>
        </div>

        <div #paypal></div>
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf='buttonError && !loginForm.valid'>Please make sure the values above are valid before checking out</span>
      </form>
    </div>
```

[Console after the checkout has been completed and onApprove() has been called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5pWR.jpg)

Comment: in network tab click on those requests. and see there method. one will be of type options.

Comment: checked bro, did you check?

Comment: I'm currently working with PayPal buttons with angular and I get the Dev tools site map warnings too.  However I don't get the supplement order one

Comment: Can you check if you somehow have duplicate buttons?  I know I had a heck of a time rendering the buttons.  I ended up using ViewChildren to make sure the div was loaded right.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the taking time to respond. Aakash, I've checked the network tab and here's the results: https://i.imgur.com/tsiIlgn.jpg . Apologies, I know it doesn't show all the requests in much detail but the bottom two are posts to my backend express server. One completes successfully but the other doesn't because the email has already been used after one completes.

Edit: I should add that non of the requests seem to be of type option throughout the checkout process. It just seems to split the checkout process into two somewhere throughout the checkout. Thank you again

Comment: Hi Nabel,

I think that the error may be part of the issue to be honest, I've looked into that error however there doesn't seem to be much on how/why it occurs. I'll have to dive a bit further I think.

I also use "@ViewChild('paypal') paypalElement: ElementRef" to access the paypal div directly so I can render it through the typescript file. I struggle to see it being an issue with a duplicate button because the other methods in the button don't seem to be called twice. There seems to be some problem half-way through the process. Thank you for responding.

Comment: The only reason I mentioned the duplicate button thing is I could somehow imagine the callback being called for both buttons but not for the initial call

Comment: It makes sense to be fair, but I just can't see where it could be duplicated. I only have one div for that button and i've checked throughout my project and I only call the SDK once. I thought it may have been due to the [hidden] attribute hiding its parent div when the page first loads because I remember having an issue when I put it in a div using the *ngIf directive. I moved it away from any parent divs and the issue still occurs though. I'll continue looking for any potential code which could lead to the button being duplicated because I agree with your theory.

Comment: I've asked about this issue over at PayPal's official github for anyone who wishes to see if a solution is found: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1321